# SharePoint 2013 workflow won't run under SharePoint App (from App Step)

Tags: sharepoint-workflow

I have two lists.  List A has a Designer workflow that uses an App Step to create a new item in another list - essentially copying the data to that list.  That works great.  However, List B has a workflow that should start when new item is created and it won't. I do have Workflow can use app permissions turned on.   I don't know what else to look for.

I have followed the instructions in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159(v=office.15).aspx .

I've been trying to find an answer for days without success.

Comment: Were you able to find/fix the problem?

Comment: @osiris: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you create an item in another list from appstep, it is created on behalf of "System Account". Any workflow which runs on 'Created' won't start if value of  "created by" is "System Account". I'll suggest you to give the user permission on  list B and take the steps to create an item out of the app step.

Comment: If you feel I answered your question, please mark it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. I am using SharePoint online. My scenario was a workflow 2013 run on an item in List A use 'start 2010 workflow' action inside 'App Step' action to turn on another 2010 workflow on the same item. It work well before. But, some how it start to fail after some minor edit on the workflow 2013. The easiest solution I can found was, move the 'start 2010 workflow' permission out of the 'App Step' section.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had a similar issue and I spent lots of efforts but nothing worked until I try SharePoint 2010 workflow instead of SharePoint 2013 designer workflow. I enabled app step that is equivalent to impersonation, but even that didn't helped. SharePoint 2013 App Step will create item on behalf of user who has published workflow, but unfortunately it would not trigger SharePoint designer workflow.

What I did is I created the same workflow but with SharePoint 2010 without App-Step and it worked like charm.